# How is the p-value greater here?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

I got this exercise from the book of Paul Newbold:

A pharmaceutical manufacturer is concerned that the
impurity concentration in pills should not exceed 3%. It
is known that from a particular production run impurity
concentrations follow a normal distribution with a
standard deviation of 0.4%. A random sample of 64 pills
from a production run was checked, and the sample
mean impurity concentration was found to be 3.07%.

a. Test at the 5% level the null hypothesis that the
population mean impurity concentration is 3%
against the alternative that it is more than 3%.

b. Find the p-value for this test.

c. Suppose that the alternative hypothesis had been
two-sided, rather than one-sided, with the null
hypothesis $H_0$ : $m = 3$. State, without doing the calculations,
whether the p-value of the test would be
higher than, lower than, or the same as that found in
part (b). Sketch a graph to illustrate your reasoning.

d. In the context of this problem, explain why a onesided
alternative hypothesis is more appropriate
than a two-sided alternative.

Well, my answer from a) and b) are (i think there are correct):

Reject the Null if $\frac {3.07 - 3}{\frac {0.4}{8}} > 1.645$
Since $1.4 < 1.645$, i dont reject the null.
The p value is $ Probability(Z>1.4) = 0.08$

Now, my problem is about the items c) and d)
Can anyone give some intuition about the answers?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Question (a) is stated poorly. A null hypothesis and its corresponding alternative hypothesis should partition the parameter space, but this pair of hypotheses, as stated, leaves out all means less than 3.

Comment: @Kodiologist Not everyone agrees with this prescription; many authors work exactly this way. There are some cases where it makes sense; others perhaps less so.

Comment: But if your alternative hypothesis doesn't include every case where the null hypothesis is false, and then you accept the alternative hypothesis on the basis of the test, haven't you inferred too much from the test? In this problem, for example, the sample mean could be below 3% and you'd conclude that the population mean is above 3%.

Comment: Note that it would only be done in the context of a one tailed test. If the sample mean was low, you would not reject the null.